# Login React Native usuario especifico en Firebase sin custom claims

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, auth

Creando el back con Firebase para un sistema de usuarios que se loguean con email and pass, estoy tratando de establecer que solo usuarios específicos puedan acceder a un componente en una app con React Native. Es decir puedo validar que el usuario este logueado, pero todos los usuarios logueados podrían crear contenido (acceder al componente), cuando solamente necesitaría que lo haga un solo usuario especifico. Lo único que encontré es utilizar custom claims, pero solo vienen en la versión Blaze(pago).

Hay alguna forma mas fácil de hacerlo o filtrar que un usuario especifico solamente pueda crear ( es decir tener acceso a determinado componente? .

Dejo el código con el que llamo a firebase y como valido el usuario este logueado, para ver si alguien conoce un método mas fácil.

Muchas gracias y un saludo

El estado y comprobación de la base

```
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userInfo) => {
            setUser(userInfo);
        });
    }, []);
```

Y la validacion para que vea el componente

```
        <View style={styles.viewBody}>
            <ListTables tables={tables} handleLoadMore={handleLoadMore} isLoading={isLoading} />
            {user && (
                <Icon
                    reverse
                    type="material-community"
                    name="plus"
                    containerStyle={styles.btnContainer}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('add-spot')}
                />
            )}
        </View>
```